# clojure read-string fraction / ratio surprisingly working

Tags: clojure

I was asked how would I parse the string "1/4" in Clojure. I replied the following (there are probably nicer ways):

```
(-> "1/25"
  (str/split #"/")
  (->> (map #(Integer/parseInt %))
       (apply /)))
```

But then I thought I'll just see what read-string does (I use it for parsing when its safe), and surprisingly:

```
(read-string "1/25")
```

Returns a `clojure.lang.Ratio`.

I didn't expect it to be able to read the expression at all. Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: `read-string` evals the input.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I actually didn't know you're allowed to write `1/3` as a literal (I usually write `(/ 1 3)`), thanks :)

Comment: The manual covers it here: https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#_ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `clojure.core/read` and `clojure.edn/read` are a "superset" of the EDN spec. They supports all valid EDN's and some other's extensions (for example, ratios)

`clojure.core/read` can evaluare code. for example `(read-string "#=(prn :hello-injection)")`, so prefer `clojure.edn/read-string` to parse inputs

AFIK, the `cljs.core/read-string` will not read ratios. also you can't use `1/2` in `.cljs` files.